# backbone JS Model / Collection (Retrieving Checked Box Ticked Value)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I currently have a list of item that is being loaded based on URL from collection.

Now i need to filter this list of item , currently the items are being populated manually hardcoded in template(html)

```
<li>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="internship" value="I"></label></li>
```

Should i populate this using model & collection instead, the question to which method which i'm asking for advice is based on How can i collect the VALUE of the checkbox TICKED.

If box is ticked , my URL sent will be different , to retrieve a new set of URL with queries.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use model & collection to render this list, this way you don't have to query DOM every time you want to check state of view. Also you change URL by subscribing change event on model and collection as needed.

Comment: Is there an Example i can try on? I'm quite new here , Dont quite get the URL & How to render using Model and collection , i'm currently using e.currentTarget to get value & checked status

Comment: example would be a bigger one, I try it sometime tomorrow